# Export the latest document to local machine

Tags: dql, documentum

I'm not familiar with Documentum, so my question is likely to be dummy, but I was wondering if somebody told me how can I pull out the latest version of a document from Documentum.

For example, if I have i_chronicle_id or a list of i_chronicle_id and I want to export latest version of that doc/docs to my local machine, how can I do that?

Also I'd be happy, If somebody pointed me out to good reference/guide of DQL and Documentum Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `i_chronicle_id` you can get latest object by this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dm_document 
    WHERE i_chronicle_id = '<i_chronicle_id>'
```

When you have `r_object_id`'s from non current version of documents you can have current version of document using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dm_document 
    WHERE i_chronicle_id 
        IN (SELECT i_chronicle_id FROM dm_document (ALL) 
            WHERE r_object_id = '<r_object_id>' )
```

Keep in mind that every query return the latest version, i.e. `CURRENT` version of the object/document. If you want to retrieve all versions of object/document you need to add the `(ALL)` keyword just after the WHERE clause. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM dm_document (ALL)
```

Of course, you want to add something in your WHERE clause since this query will return lots of rows.

As for the DQL reference guide, you can always download it from ECM support site or find some version around the network, for example [here](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Fipg%2Ftools%2Fwcm-portal%2Fdocumentation%2Fassets%2Fdql_reference_guide_en.pdf&ei=NiVMVMSjKaKV7AbVlYEQ&usg=AFQjCNGYn3nypX-c71_f1M6ZePPRKCv4pA&sig2=G6uWkirlA4GhhD1xhPSwSw&bvm=bv.77880786,d.ZGU&cad=rja) (very old one though, but good enough for starter). 
Same for the Documentum Java API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So, am I right in saying that the query you provided can be used to fetch CURRENT document by its r_object_id.
And if I want to get CURRENT document by i_chronicle_id, I just can use then next query:


`SELECT * FROM dm_document WHERE i_chronicle_id = '<i_chronicle_id>'`


And to get all CURRENT r_object_id of docs that are stored in documentum, I can select


`SELECT r_object_id FROM dm_documentum`

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to add more details regarding your comment.

Comment: Thank you! A great detailed answer. You really helped me to get first brief introduction to DQL and dm_document.

Comment: One more thing about it: Documentum is the platform and dm_document is the root type of objects that can have content attached to it. I see you still mix those things. Good luck with Documentum! :D